# Get ICollection property of generic type

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, icollection

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC 5, I need get the Icollection property and search into other property, if printed the result of the first search is fine, but when i go to search in the result is null.

what is the problem?

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = db.Users.Include( u=> u.Sucursales)
                   .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
                   .SingleOrDefault();

if( user != null )
{
    var sucursal = user.Sucursales.Include(s => s.Emisor)
                                  .Where(s => s.ID == suc)
                                  .SingleOrDefault();
    if (sucursal != null)
    {
        var tipoCfe = sucursal.Emisor.TiposCfe
                                     .Where(t => t.ID == factura)
                                     .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Could you be more specific. Which result is null?

Comment: sucursal == null, but the sucursal.ID == suc is in user.Sucursales.

Comment: Where is the value of `suc` set, and what to?

Comment: Difficult one. I see nothing wrong with the code. Are you 100% sure Sucursales contains elements and the variable 'suc' has the correct value?

Comment: Yes, 'suc' variable is fine and s.ID == suc is in user.Sucursales. 

Is posible that the query is executed after the if(sucursal != null)?

Comment: @Maske, the query should take place right away since you are using SingleOrDefault(), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460504/single-or-default-with-condition-or-where-clause. Your Include(s => s.Emisor) sticks out to me though, since it wasn't included when fetching the user.

Comment: What is `Sucursales`'s type and how is it defined in `User`? You shouldn't be able to do `user.Sucursales.Include`, because it should be `ICollection` (or similar) but not `IQueryable`.

Comment: More on include method... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx You may have to do something like: db.Users.Include("Sucursales.Emisor")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will take place right away since you are using `SingleOrDefault()`, see [this StackOverflow question pertaining to SingleOrDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460504/single-or-default-with-condition-or-where-clause) Your `Include(s => s.Emisor)` sticks out to me though. Since Emisor wasn't included when fetching the user, you will not be able to request that since your query is no longer of type IQueryable. Your query has already been executed.

In order to retrieve the data you require, you will have to obtain the data during your first query. I would do something similar to: `db.Users.Include("Sucursales.Emisor")` when you retrieve the user.

More on include method... [MSDN Explanation of Include Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
var user = db.Users.Include( u=> u.Sucursales)
```

for

```
var user = db.Users.Include("Sucursales.Emisor")
```

Comment: If you want a type-safe method use `db.Users.Include(u=> u.Sucursales.Select(s => s.Emisor))`.